# Trigger for replying to a message in TEAMS from a keyword keeps looping

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

I am using Power Automate to look for a keyword in a message posted in a channel in TEAMS and then send a reply. The problem is the reply message keeps sending and I have no idea why.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found the solution, you probably need to check if the reply contains some string noticing that it's an automated reply.

message contain key word(s)
Yes: does message contain "automation string"
Yes: don't reply.
No: Send automation reply
No: ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).